# How to remedy Workbooks not closing properly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently writing a macro that will allow you to select a folder, set bounds, and then loop through some numbers to read in all of a certain file type. (Excel in this instance.)

You can see that right here

```
Dim StringP1 As String
Dim iterator As Integer
Dim StringP2 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim final As Integer

'number of files
final = 5


'main folder
StringP1 = " FOLDER NAME "
StringP2 = ".xls"
i = 1

While i < final

    iterator = 1
    FileName = StringP1 & iterator & StringP2

    Call attempt1(FileName)
    Call attempt2(FileName)

    i = (i + 1)
    iterator = (iterator + 1)
Wend
```

when it loads into my subs it uses this code

```
Sub attempt1(FN As String)

Dim Excel As New Excel.Application
Dim FileName As String

Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set MyRec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Infor")

Excel.Workbooks.Open (FN)
```

Then it goes through some code, and eventually ends up exiting the subroutine. 
Everything I've tried seems to fail.

I've been messing with this for a few hours, using various things I've found from Stackoverflow and other VBA sites, but nothing seems to work.

I've tried using

```
excel.workbooks.close savechanges:=false
workbook.close
workbooks.close
.
.
.
```

I'm curious if anyone knows a good way to exit all of these EXCEL.EXE that open?

Comment: If there's only one sheet on the workbook you're opening try moving it to the workbook containing your project. The Application should close when there are no more sheets.

Comment: Is this possible to do with an access database?

Comment: Untested, but maybe try rid of `Set XL = CreateObject...` and add `Excel.Quit` to quit the application. Though I wouldn't use the variable name `Excel` in `Dim Excel As New Excel.Application`, maybe `XL` there

Comment: You declare variable Excel but then Set variable XL. Should be `Dim XL...` Should have `Option Explicit` at the top of every code module.

Comment: You create an early-bound `Excel.Application` object, name if `Excel`, and then create *another*, late-bound, and name it `XL`. You only need one of them; consider keeping the early-bound one and dropping the late-bound one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to close all workbooks (Excel files).
Proper way to close single workbook by its name:

```vb
    XL.Workbooks("filename.xls").Close Savechanges:=False
```

If you have many workbooks to close you may use a cycle like this:

```vb
Public Sub WorkWithExcel()
    Dim XL As New Excel.Application, WB As Excel.Workbook
    ' Open Excel file:
    XL.Workbooks.Open ("my_file.xls")
    ' Open another Excel file
    XL.Workbooks.Open ("another my file.xls")
    ' do some work with this files
    ' ...
    ' For every file in our application:
    For Each WB In XL.Workbooks
        ' Close file without saving changes:
        WB.Close savechanges:=False
    Next WB
    ' Close Excel applicatioin:
    XL.Quit
    ' Clear object:
    Set XL = Nothing
End Sub
```